# Safari Redirecting http to (non-existent) https

Tags: macos, safari, http

Safari forces a redirect to the https version of a site I previously visited via https.

However, the https site no longer works and there is no way to prevent Safari form trying to load it.

[image: HTTP redirects to HTTPS]

Here is a related Apple Forums question, [Safari keeps redirecting http to https](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7217573?searchText=Safari%20Redirects%20to%20HTTPS)

Answer (score 36):

*HSTS Policy* is now included in Safari's stored website data, and you can remove domain.com data to clear this issue.

1. `command + ,`
2. **Privacy** -> **Manage Website Data**...
3. Search *domain.com*
4. Click **Remove**

Change `https://domain.com` to `http://domain.com` in your address bar and click return key.

Note: if you are having a problem with `subdomain.domain.com` you still must delete the parent `domain.com` data.

Comment: This applies not only to `localhost`, but to any domains. Note, that in order to access **subdomain**, you have to remove **parent domain's data**.
I.e. if you want to access `http://some.subdomain.somehost.com` and get redirected to `https`, you have to search for `somehost.com` at the `Manage Website Data` page and remove it.

Comment: This answer worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 35):

If the site has previously indicated to Safari that it wishes to always be accessed over HTTPS through HSTS ([HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)), then Safari will always try to redirect to HTTPS.

You can clear the HSTS cache by deleting `~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist`.

Note that Safari does also cache 301 redirects for a while and thus clearing the normal Safari cache may also be necessary: from the Develop menu (enable in Preferences → Advanced), choose Empty Caches.

#For 2020...

In current MacOS, you must

1. Clear the cache in Safari. (Developer menu.) Then immediately:
2. Quit Safari, and any other apps that may use networking (quit all apps)
3. Open `/Users/ your user name /Library/Cookies` which will look like:

[image]

4. Throw `HSTS.plist` in the trash, **then immediately restart the whole Mac.**

In extreme cases, turn off all bandwidth to the Mac before steps 1-2-3-4.

In current MacOS, the HSTS list is immediately rebuilt if the file is thrown away, if any networking happens. Hence the Mac needs an immediate restart for trashing to work.

Comment: One more thing. For me to get out of https for particular domain, I had to disable `Limit IP Address Tracking` under System Preferences > Network.
I also disabled `Hide IP address` under Privacy tab of Safari settings.

Answer (score 11):

Since December 2017, Google has added ".dev" TLD to the preloaded HSTS list for Chrome!

Safari uses the same list. So Safari will always add *.dev to HSTS list...

Seems many developers will need to change .dev suffix to another one :(

See: [Chrome to force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/)

Answer (score 9):

I haven't found any working solution but for a workaround use
127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

```
http://localhost/

http://127.0.0.1/
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems Safari enters into this mad behaviour when you have accessed localhost using a client side certificate. In my case, one of the projects I work with needs this client side setup and it totally wrecks development for the projects where I can't use http on localhost. The only workaround I have found is to edit `/etc/hosts` and add an alias for localhost, like so

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Then use I can use http://localhost:3000 to access my project on port 3000 without Safari forcing a https connection.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this 'Safari HSTS Cache' problem.

I tried the solution `rm ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist`, but it does not work.

But the following steps are useful:

1. Quit Safari
2. `rm -f ~/Library/Cookies/HSTS.plist`, remove HSTS cache file
3. `killall nsurlstoraged`, to stop HTTP storage manager (because it has an in-memory cache of the HSTS hosts)

The most important is, service nsurlstoraged has a in-memory HSTS cache, must reload this service.