# Safari says IP address isn't valid but other browsers can access it

Tags: macos, safari, http

I have a Raspberry Pi set up with WordPress using a reserved IP address `192.168.x.yyy` and I don't have SSL set up yet, so only HTTP not HTTPS. When I try to go to that address (`http://192.168.x.yyy`) on Safari I get the error: Safari can't open the page `www.192.168.x.yyy` because the page's address isn't valid.

I'm able to load the page using MS Edge, Opera, Firefox, and Chrome. I get the note that the site isn't secure, but it loads on all these browsers. Any suggestions on how to get Safari to access my site?

Comment: What exactly did you type? Did you type the http:// part or just the address

Comment: There’s really no reason to obfuscate your non-routable address. Anyone that is on your network can see that with a port scan and no one outside your network can connect to the [192.168.0.0/24 Reserved IP Address block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses).

Comment: I entered the full address but did not terminate it, maybe that was the issue. Wasn't sure about outside access but now that you say it it does seem kind of obvious. In any case I've since implemented SSL and now the site comes up in Safari with no issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost always an issue with the web search hijacking your address you type. (Especially when it pre-fills the old wrong correction.)

Be sure you terminate the IP address.

- http://192.168.2.123/

Then you may have to turn off the autocomplete or change your search engine in Safari. It may also be worthwhile to [check and clear your HSTS settings](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/215077/5472).

Comment: Thanks bmike, I think it was that I didn't terminate the address and I appreciate the note about clearing the HSTS settings, wasn't aware of that.